Can I use 2x4 blocks to support pipes running parallel to joists?
I am replacing some plumbing in my basement, going from 3/4" copper to 1" pex. The pipes will run parallel to the joists.
Is it OK to cut a 2x4 to the width of the joist area and attach them to the bottom of the joists? e.g. it would be like having a 1.5" block between the joists at the bottom only. The pipes would be strapped to the top of these 2x4s.
If this approach is OK, does it make a difference if I use screws or nails to fasten the 2x4s to the joists? I'm inclined to use screws because I have a right angle drill and not much room to swing a hammer, but wonder if this would prevent necessary flex between the joists in a way that nails would not.

If it's for hot water, remember to add insulation, in case that means you need to add a bit of extra space around the pipes.

You should also consider using tube talons to attach the pex directly to the joists. That's likely easier, far cheaper, and shouldn't have any effect on the joists at all.

@bta, that's a fine option. I was initially worried about the weight of the pipes, but after looking it up a 1" pipe only holds 0.04 gallons per foot of length - so it's not as heavy as I was thinking.

That's fine, if a bit overkill. I'd use screws just because nailing through aged joists is a bear, especially at the slight angle that's necessary. You could also pilot for nails or screws. 2½" is a good length.

Your plan is sound and there isn't any problems with attaching 2x4s with screws.
The joists shouldn't move anyway, so you are good to go.

The configuration should be such that condesation on the pipes does not run down from the pipes down onto any wood.
